# Ошибка при построении апк файла

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, gradle, build

выдает ошибку когда пытаешься сделать "build apk"

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzb;
```

вот мой app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sergey.firebasechat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

помогите пожалуйста совсем немогу понять как это решить

если добавить вот это         `multiDexEnabled true;`

то выдает вот такую ошибку

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/iid/zzc.class
```

Comment: в папке libs что-то есть? 
попробуйте убрать apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: @Andriy Martsinkevych если я удаляю то что вы говорите ошибка уходит но и программа перестает работать. Папка libs пуста

Comment: какую ошибку получаете?

Comment: @Andriy Martsinkevych Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто добавьте в блок `dependencies`:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
сompile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.1.0'
```

Всегда соблюдайте совместимость версий указанных [здесь](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]